# How to move from AppStore and PlayMarket to Enterprise to implement white labeling for different companies?

Tags: android, ios, white-labelling, software-product-lines

my client wants to remove our application from AppStore and PlayMarket and distribute it privately to his and other companies (B2B). Our company has D-U-N-S number, but still it is not official company with employees. That's why I excluded the option to move to Apple Enterprise Program (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I did some investigations and realized that the best way to implement it on iOS is to use existing Apple Developer Program with Apple Business Manager.

But how can I distribute apps to the users? My client wants to have just one link which automatically downloads application.

Also, I need some similar solution for Android users and it seems that Enterprise on Android is very hard to implement.

Comment: The best way to distribute a B2B app via Apple Business Manager is for the devices to be managed by an MDM. The MDM can then make the app available via a private App Store or even push the app.  If you don't use an MDM then you will need to distribute redemption codes to the users.

Comment: @Paulw11 what about android? do they have the similar solution for B2B apps?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.  I know you can side load apps in Android, so that might be an option; There are some hoops to jump through with regard to trusting side loaded apps.  Again an MDM would probably make this simple.